# KOMA-Script Headlines: Problem with underlining and pagestyle on onesided-print

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I've got some code provided by Markus Kohm (KOMA-Script author) in „Die TeXnische Komödie“ (members journal of german TeX users group) volume 3/2012. He's showing how to easily modify the headlines with KOMA-Script. I now have the following code which is basically copied from the journal (so it's Markus', not mine)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\setheadsepline{0.5pt}
\lehead[\pagemark]{\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{\pagemark}\hspace{\marginparsep}\headmark}
\rohead[\pagemark]{\headmark\hspace{\marginparsep}\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\pagemark}}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
  \ifodd\value{page}\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{\pnumbar\enskip\thepage}%
  \else\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\thepage\enskip\pnumbar}%
  \fi
}%
\newcommand*{\pnumbar}{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{%
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1.5pt}{1.1\baselineskip}%
  }%
}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
  \setheadwidth[0pt]{%
    \dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax
  }%
}%
\recalctypearea
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

When adding the `twoside`-option to `\documentclass` I get the page numbers positioned as expected (screenshots cut together):
[image: Result of twosided print]

While with `oneside` the positioning of the page number on even pages is wrong:
[image: Result of onesided print]

I can image that the problem is happening due to the `\ifodd` check. Is there a possibility to react on whether `twoside` or `oneside` option is set to fix this and have all pages with `oneside` to be the same?

As—as you can see—the seperation line between the head and the main text is way to long. This was added by me but I don't know how to make it shorter, so it has only the length of the text width (and maybe stopping at the vertical marker next to the page number). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That template doesn't seem to accommodate for `oneside`, but can be modified to.

EDIT: I think I fixed your problem with the length of the head separation line.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\setheadsepline{0.5pt}
\lehead[\pagemark]{\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{\pagemark}\hspace{\marginparsep}\headmark}
\rohead[\pagemark]{\headmark\hspace{\marginparsep}\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\pagemark}}

\makeatletter
\if@twoside%
    \renewcommand*{\pagemark}{%
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \ifodd\value{page}\makebox[0pt][l]{\pnumbar\enskip\thepage}%
    \else\makebox[0pt][r]{\thepage\enskip\pnumbar}%
    \fi%
}%
\else%
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{%
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\pnumbar\enskip\thepage}%
}%
\fi%
\makeatother


\newcommand*{\pnumbar}{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{%
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1.5pt}{1.1\baselineskip}%
  }%
}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
  \setheadwidth[0pt]{%
    \dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax%+\marginparwidth\relax
  }%
}%
\recalctypearea
\begin{document}
\Blindtext \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

If the `twoside` option is loaded:

[image]
[image]

If the `twoside` option is *not* loaded:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Jubobs. Do have an idea how to solve the problem with the head separation line that is way to long?

Comment: What do you mean? Does it extend to much into the margin for your taste?

Comment: Yes. I wanted it to only be from the left start of the text to the vertical line before the page number (or vice versa on a even page in twosided printing). I think it's happening because of the `\setheadwidth` command in the `\AfterCalculatingTypearea` hook but I have no idea how to fix it for the line to make it work in both one- and twosided printings

Comment: I'm not very familiar with KOMA-script classes and their mechanics. Wait for someone more competent to address that particular issue.